# Elementary divisors of the multiplicative group $(Z/99Z)^× × (Z/56Z)^×$

Tags: group-theory

I'm trying to find the elementary divisors of the following: $(Z/99Z)^× × (Z/56Z)^×$

I tried to do this by first assuming that:  $|(Z/99Z)^×| = 98$ and that $|(Z/56Z)^×|=55$.

Then: $(Z/99Z)^×$ is isomorphic to $(Z/98Z)$ and that $(Z/56Z)^×$ is isomorphic to $(Z/55Z)$.

So then: $(Z/98Z)$ is isomorphic to $(Z/2Z) × (Z/7Z) × (Z/7Z)$ and $(Z/55Z)$ is isomorphic to $(Z/5Z) × (Z/11Z)$.

Therefore I concluded that $(Z/98Z)×(Z/55Z)$ is isomorphic to $(Z/2Z) × (Z/7Z) × (Z/7Z)×(Z/5Z) × (Z/11Z)$, so that the elementary divisors of $(Z/99Z)^× × (Z/56Z)^×$ are $2,5,7$ and $11$.

Unfortunately, this was incorrect. Can someone help me understand where I went wrong? Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: $\mathrm{card}((Z/99Z)^{\times}) = 60$ and $\mathrm{card}((Z/56Z)^{\times}) = 24$

Comment: Your third sentence is wrong. And $(Z/nZ)^\times$ is not usually cyclic.

Comment: @Axel Could you maybe explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit too long to be a comment.

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}^*$ then $(\mathbb{Z}_{ /n\mathbb{Z}})^{\times}$ is a group with $\varphi(n)$ elements, where $\varphi$ is Euler's totient function.

Moreover,

$$\varphi(n) = n \prod_{p \in \mathcal{P}_n}\left(1-\dfrac{1}{p}\right)$$

where $\mathcal{P}_n$ is the set of primes intervening in the prime factorization of $n$.

Hence $\varphi(n) = n-1 $ if and only if $n$ is prime.

Furthermore as $99 = 3^2 \times 11$ and $56=2^3\times 7$ then,

$$\varphi(99)=99\left(1-\frac{1}{3}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{11}\right) = 60$$

$$\varphi(56) = 56\left(1-\frac{1}{2} \right)\left(1-\frac{1}{7} \right) = 24 $$